# How to add image link to firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to add an image to firebase and while the image is uploading to my storage it is not uploading to my database. How can I fix this?

This is the code I have for that section

```
for (let i = 0; i < filess.length; i++) {
    storage.ref(refUUID + '/' + filess[i].name).put(filess[i]).then(() => {
        storage.ref(refUUID + '/' + filess[i].name).getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
            database.ref(listingType + '/' + refUUID + '/Description/Images/Image' + (i + 1)).set({
                Link: url,
                name: 'Image' + (i + 1)
            })
        });
    });
}
```